# Solving recurrence relations using generating functions: $ a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}^2 a_{n}^3$, where: $ a_{1} = a_{0} = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have to solve given recurrence relation: $ a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}^2  a_{n}^3$, where: $ a_{1} = a_{0} = 1.$

I have no idea how to do it honestly, I have calculated that first values of $a_{n}$ are (1, 1, 2, 8, 1024...). $a_{5}$ is so big that I will not put it down here.

I've tried using generating functions to solve it but with no success. I don't know how to split given sequence in order to receive couple of generating functions so that I can solve them. Maybe we have to use auxiliary sequence for that?

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps let $b_n:=\log_{2} a_n$ and take it from there?

Comment: So I would have $b_{n+2} = log_{2}(2a_{n+1}) + log_{2}(a_{n}^3)$ and then I should put it inside a generating function and calculate?

Comment: Oh come on, you'd have $b_{n+2}=1+2b_{n+1}+3b_{n}$, and putting $B(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{|\infty}b_k x^k$ you easily express $B(x)$ as a rational function, do partial fractions, identify coefficient of $x^n$ and bingo.

Comment: Okay, I will try to calculate it and post my results in a while.

Comment: So I got $B(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-2x-3x^2)(1-x)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks the right shape, but I haven't checked.

Comment: Are you sure that this $b_{n+2}$ formula of your is correct? How did you actually come up with this?

Comment: I took logarithms of the original equation.

Comment: So after partial fractioning my B(x) I have received a final formula for $B(x) = \frac{1}{8(x+1)} - \frac{1}{8(3x-1)} - \frac{1}{4(1-x)}$. How do I convert it to sums now so that I can get my final answer?

Comment: Indentify the coefficients of $x^k$ in $B(x)$, it's the sum of three GPs. So $b_{k}=\frac{1}{8} (-1)^k +\frac{1}{8} 3^k -\frac{1}{4}$. Then $a_k=2^{b_k}$ and you're done.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on how did you come up with these sums of GPs? I know that the coefficients are respectively: $\frac{1}{8}$, $-\frac{1}{8}$ and $-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-at}=\sum a^k t^k$.

Comment: So my final answer would be: $$a_{n} = 2^{\frac{1}{8}(-1)^n + \frac{1}{8}3^n - \frac{1}{4}} $$

Comment: Looks good. Well done.

Comment: Thanks you kindly!

Answer (score 2):

First transform your recurrence: Let $b_n = \log a_n$, and:

$\begin{align*}
\log a_{n + 2}
  &= \log 2 + 2 \log a_{n + 1} + 3 \log a_n \\
b_{n + 2} 
  &= 2 b_{n + 1} + 3 b_n + \log 2
\end{align*}$

Now use generating functions. Define $B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n$, multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize the resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n + 2} z^n
    &= 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n + 1} z^n
         + 3 \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n
         + \log 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
  \frac{B(z) - b_0 - b_1 z}{z^2}
     &= 2 \frac{B(z) - b_0}{z}
          + 3 B(z) + \frac{\log 2}{1 - z} \\
\end{align*}$

Use the initial values $b_0 = b_1 = 0$, solve for $B(z)$ and express as partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
  B(z)
    &= \frac{z^2}{1 - 3 z - z^2 + 3 z^2} \log 2 \\
    &=  \frac{\log 2}{8 (1 - 3 z)}
         + \frac{\log 2}{8 (1 + z)}
         - \frac{\log 2}{4 (1 - z)}
\end{align*}$

Everything in sight is just geometric series:

$\begin{align*}
   b_n
     &= \frac{\log 2}{8} \cdot 3^n
           + \frac{\log 2}{8} \cdot (-1)^n
           - \frac{\log 2}{4} \\
   a_n
     &= 2^{3^n / 8 + (-1)^n / 8 - 1 / 4}
\end{align*}$